# How to prevent browser to re-set inputs on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

As you know, when we have inputs in our HTML forms (checkbox, input or textarea), when we refresh (with f5 for example) Firefox sets the filled values. What should I do to prevent this?

I expect all my fields would be blank and default checkboxes and select inputs in all pages, but when I reload, the browser sets them to filled values.

Comment: Iterate through them with Javascript and clear them.

Comment: I dont want to clear them , I want their default values and I got hundreds of pages, so I can not write script for every pages

Answer (score 2):

You can add attribute `autocomplete="off"` to form element. But it will also disable autocomplete form inputs after focusing them. Which may be unwanted.

Comment: it workes, but it needs to rewrite all inputs and forms, I tried add this property after document ready , but it seems it doesn't work in that way

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately assign autocomplete off by JS is not working. Firefox fill them before. I dont have any other JS solution. If it's possible, I would try batch search and replace (e.g. in VS Code) to add autocomplete="off" to form elements (setting inputs should not be necessary).

Comment: Instead of adding the attribute in a script you could consider adding the form in a script to the DOM after load, but I guess you need a proper build environment to change all your pages for it. On the other hand, why make it harder for your users...

Answer (score 2):

Use it is in your form tag

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="#" method="get">
```

and for fire fox, you should try it (individual form inputs)

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: it workes, but it needs to rewrite all inputs and forms, I tried add this property after document ready , but it seems it doesn't work in that way

Comment: call this function on your required event like (onload, reset) =>  function autocompleteoff(){ $("form input").attr("autocomplete", "off");}

Answer (score 1):

If all the input fields are in a form field you can simply use `.reset()` and run it after the page load to reset all the form fields.

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
 document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $('#inputId').val('');
});
```

Comment: Please add more comment  to explain the code you provided